# Merge tags [lodash] and [lodash-es]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Today I've discovered tag [lodash-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash-es). This tag is a reference to

> The Lodash library exported as ES modules

So it's just a [repackaging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es) of the well know [lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash) library. I'd suggest to merge [lodash-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash-es) into tag [lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash), or at least make it a synonymous for it.

Comment: This is what we have tags for. It is an extremely useful feature, just by adding the  lodash-es tag to a question, you can tell the entire world that the question is about lodash and specifically about the es6 branch of the library, which has its own repo and long developer history. But for some reason, you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: @davidkonrad does it matter for the question? I honestly don't know - that's the first time I heard of `lodash-es` but my initial assumption is that it has the same functionality as the main build, so any question for it would be applicable for both. If that isn't the case, then we do need two tags, I agree. A quick check shows me that `lodash-es` has a very low usage overall - 23 questions over one and a half years. [And there are only 4 questions tagged `lodash-es` without `lodash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lodash-es+-lodash) so very few people seem to find it useful.

Comment: Wow, and now I looked at the 4 questions solely tagged `lodash-es` - 1 wasn't really tied to it being an ES module, so could have been tagged as both or just `lodash`. The other three each boil down to "Don't use lodash-es, use lodash instead". They are all about how importing lodash-es doesn't work and it's because it's an ES module, while lodash is a CommonJS module, which works for importing. So far, it seems the only real use the tag has gotten is that the library it's about shouldn't have been used. That's an odd situation to be in.

Comment: @VLAZ ..."*so very few people seem to find it useful.*"  ... **or**, there are at the moment just a few questions specifically targeting lodash es6, and we can conclude that users actually find the lodash-es6 tag useful, because they think it is important to indicate that the es6 branch is in question. And why should that not be important? It is two different code bases.

Comment: Also a [lodash-amd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-amd) package exists. 
All current available packages are build using the same lodash-cli, as reported in the lodash [custom builds docs](https://lodash.com/custom-builds): _Valid exports are “amd”, “commonjs”, “es”, “global”, “node”, “npm”, “none”, & “umd”_. Do we need to add a tag for each lib build?

Comment: Would they automatically add the main `lodash` tag?

Comment: @VLAZ Tag popularity isn't the only thing to be considered, though.

Comment: @jhpratt neither is it irrelevant.

Comment: Why wouldn't they just tag it with both `lodash` and `esmodules`?  Why do we need a compositional tag?  If they have tagged `lodash-es` then they are likely having an issue with esmodules, not just the lodash specific exported modules.

Comment: @zero298 I totally agree with you